# Create AWS SG using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to create a security group within a specific vpc by passing the variables during the code execution but I get the following errors, when I run the following command with the variables.

```
./create_sg.py vpc-e79569b2 dev_test_sg testing tcp 22 22 0.0.0.0/0
```

> An error occurred (InvalidVpcID.NotFound) when calling the CreateSecurityGroup operation: The vpc ID 'VPC_ID' does not exist

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
region = "us-west-1"

VPC_ID=sys.argv[0]
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[1]
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[2]
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[3]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[4]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[5]
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[6]


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_vpcs()

vpc_id = 'VPC_ID'

try:
    response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='SECURITY_GROUP_NAME',Description='DESCRIPTION',VpcId=vpc_id)
    security_group_id = response['GroupId']
    print('Security Group Created %s in vpc %s.' % (security_group_id, vpc_id))

    data = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=security_group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': 'IP_PROTOCOL_1',
             'FromPort': FROM_PORT_1,
             'ToPort': TO_PORT_1,
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': 'CIDR_IP_1'}]}
        ])
    print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

Please review the code and let me know if I need to change something in there to successfully create a security group.

Answer (score 3):

This line is all wrong...

`response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='SECURITY_GROUP_NAME',Description='DESCRIPTION',VpcId=vpc_id)`

IMO it should be:

`response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,Description=DESCRIPTION,VpcId=VPC_ID)`

---

Ok, here is the complete code with corrections made to the string literals:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
region = "us-west-1"

VPC_ID=sys.argv[0]
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[1]
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[2]
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[3]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[4]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[5]
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[6]

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_vpcs()

try:
    response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,Description=DESCRIPTION,VpcId=VPC_ID)
    security_group_id = response['GroupId']
    print('Security Group Created %s in vpc %s.' % (security_group_id, VPC_ID))

    data = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=security_group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': IP_PROTOCOL_1,
             'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1),
             'ToPort': int(TO_PORT_1),
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': CIDR_IP_1}]}
        ])
    print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: You are right, this line is incorrect. However, the actual error is in line `vpc_id = 'VPC_ID'` as @spg mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Fair enough, though the code would then be inconsistant. I would say that the `vpc_id = 'VPC_ID'` line is unnecessary. Then the line which I commented on needs the quotes removing too. Otherwise the GroupName and Description would not have the text that you pass into the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed, but you are using string literals (in single quotes) in the create_security_group call rather than the variable names that you provided.

Comment: Security GroupCreated sg-123f8176 in vpc vpc-e79569b2.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_sg.py", line 37, in <module>
    'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': CIDR_IP_1}]}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 317, in _api_call
.......
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter IpPermissions[0].ToPort, value: 22, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>
Invalid type for parameter IpPermissions[0].FromPort, value: 22, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>`

Comment: @MattD, I'm sorry. Not sure where to include init(). Can you please help me with the edit?

Comment: That fixed it. You're awesome !! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries, always happy to help. I'm assuming you'll be accepting this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the quotes around `'VPC_ID'`:

```
vpc_id = VPC_ID
```